# Using functions concatenated with strings inside a variable

Tags: urls

Trying to do some dynamic image sourcing but I'm stuck. Probably pretty basic stuff, but I'm new to this.

This works:

```
<img src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/LakeArnaulMap-<?php the_ID();?>.png"/>
```

Why doesnt this:

```
<?php 
$my_img = '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/MyImage' . the_ID() . '.png"/>';
echo $my_img;
?>
```

Comment: Please read the codex documentation for `the_ID()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Comment: Use `get_bloginfo()` and `get_the_ID()` to return the result instead of print it.

Comment: *The Codex is your friend* ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) echoes the output in place. If you look at the source you will see that `template_url` is not where you expect it to be.

Use [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead, or even better use [`get_stylesheet_directory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)